# How do I access a variable defined in my jenkins pipeline with gatsby?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gatsby

I have a Gatsby project that is integrated with a jenkins CI/CD pipeline. I define a variable in the jenkins pipeline like so:

```
environment {
   my_env = "${env.GIT_BRANCH"
}
```

I have pipelines that run from the dev and master branches of the repo hosting my Gatsby project. I want to use this variable in my Gatsby config file so that when I run a pipeline gatsby will pull content from either the dev or master environments of the CMS I'm using.

The problem is Gatsby seems only able to read environment variables from .env files out of the box. I am not sure how to get it to read  variable from something that's not a .env but also stored in the root (in this case, a jenkinsfile). Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your enviornment variable in jenkinsfile,and using the same agent , then you can just access that variable using env..

```
environment {
 MY_ENV_VAR="myvalue"
}

// you can access using:
env.MY_ENV_VAR
```